# Print email's body on Outlook with Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I've been trying to print the email's body from the emails that I receive in Outlook for a while, but I'm having the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\RMBORGE\Desktop\PythonLib\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 10, in <module>
    print(message.body)
  File "C:\Users\RMBORGE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 543, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

Could someone help me?

Please see my code below:

```
from email import message
import email
import win32com.client as client

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()

print(message.body)
```

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you try a different property, (e.g. Subject) instead of Body? What happens if you use GetFirst instead of GetLast?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I can print the subject and the recipients without any error, this only happens when trying to print the body of the email.
Tried to GetLast but had the same error.

Comment: Have you tried getting another item and printing the message body? Do you get the same results with other items?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, also the email that I'm trying to print is a plain text.

Comment: Is this the mail item? Did you have a chance to check the message class if these items?

Comment: Try the `Class` property on the problematic message. What does it return?

Comment: Is showing IPM.Note

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items - mails, documents, notes and etc. Before accessing any properties specific to a particular item type I'd recommend checking the `MessageClass` property first to make sure that you deal with a mail item and the required property exists for the item chosen.

See [How to determine type of an outlook item in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107032/how-to-determine-type-of-an-outlook-item-in-python) for more information.

Another possible reason is security triggers in the Outlook object model. Read more about that in the [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings) article. Possible routes to avoid such triggers are:

1. Use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Or just consider using any wrapper around that API such as Redemption.
2. Use components for turning on/off security issues in Outlook, see [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php).
3. Use group policy to configure security issues when dealing with OOM.
4. Install any antivirus software with latest databases.